# Canning pickles and sealing lids

Tags: storage-method, canning

I did the whole boiling process of canning the pickles and over night some did not seal but as soon as I placed them in the fridge they sealed. Do they need to stay in the fridge or can I put them in the basement with the others?

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices for those jars that did not vacuum seal:

1. Treat them as refrigerator pickles, and eat them in the next several weeks.
2. Within 24 hours of the first processing, process them *again* completely (using clean, new lids and having cleaned the jar mouths)

Comment: they did end of sealing just not until I put them in the fridge for a few minutes. so leave all them in the fridge (5quarts)?

Comment: @EmilyWoodford Yup, or reprocess, like the answer says. See also [this page](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/general/cooling_jars_test_seals.html). Because they didn't seal at room temperature, you know the seals are questionable, and will likely fail if you take them out of the refrigerator.